# ansible debug stdout_lines under results, search for string then execute new play based upon when condition

Tags: ansible

Ansible debug stdout_lines under results, search for string then execute new play based upon when condition

```
- hosts: server-a
  become: yes
  gather_facts: false

  vars_files:
     - filename.yml

  tasks:

    - shell: whoami
      with_items:
        - "{{ users }}"
      become_user: "{{ item }}"
      register: play

    - debug:
        msg: System {{ inventory_hostname }}
      when: play['results'] contains specific string
```

Comment: replace `when: play['results'] contain specific string` to `when: play.stdout is contains "specific string"`

Comment: Thanks arty,getting below. "The conditional check 'play.stdout is contains \"Specific String\"' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (play.stdout is contains \"Specific String\"): 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'\n\nThe error appears to be in plabook

Comment: Try to iterate list play.results via `with_items: "{{ play.results }}"` and check via `when: "{{ item.stdout == 'specific string'}}"`

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick, this is what i used without {{ }}   when: item.stdout is contains 'Specific String' and with_items: play.results

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation you are going to [registering the result set in a loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop) in one variable. You will get therefore an dictionary and in your example and probably errors like

> *The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout_lines'*

You may try the following example

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    USERNAME: ['{{ ansible_user }}'] # list of users, even if there is one element only
    PASSWORD: '{{ ansible_password }}'

  tasks:

  - name: Who am I
    shell:
      cmd: who am i | cut -d ' ' -f 1
    check_mode: false
    register: task
    loop: "{{ USERNAME }}" #list

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      var: task
    when: ansible_check_mode

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "System {{ inventory_hostname }}"
    when: item.stdout == ansible_user # raw Jinja2 expression without double curly braces
    loop: "{{ task.results }}" # list
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ ansible_user }}" # with USERNAME looped over to limit the display output
```

Please take also note that according documentation [Basic conditionals with `when`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-ansible-facts)

> *The `when` clause is a raw Jinja2 expression without double curly braces*